# ¿Como buscar la información de un usuario en dos o mas tablas?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Estoy realizando una base de datos donde tengo profesores y estudiantes, y cada uno tiene su respectivo usuario

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se si este bien desarrollado el modelo

pero deseo obtener la información del usuario ya sea profesor o estudiante

```
SELECT *
FROM USER
INNER JOIN PROFESSOR
ON PROFESSOR.id_user = USER.id
INNER JOIN STUDENT
ON STUDENT.id_user = USER.id
WHERE USER.username = 'AG432'
```

si realizo las consultas por separado si me arroja el resultado

```
SELECT STUDENT.name
FROM USER
INNER JOIN STUDENT
ON STUDENT.id_user = USER.id
WHERE USER.username = '12345'

name
----------
Juan Perez


SELECT PROFESSOR.name
FROM USER
INNER JOIN PROFESSOR
ON PROFESSOR.id_user = USER.id
WHERE USER.username = 'AER3'

name
--------------
Alberto Cortez
```

Sabiendo que el rfc y el control_number son el username

Comment: yo invertiría los valores en el ON es decir user.id = professor.id_user

Comment: le puedo ayudar a solucionar el problemas, pero necesito que me pase la  sentencias mysql para hace pruebas

Comment: quitaria el segundo ON, ya que estas tratando obtener la info de un usuario en especifico según tu propio enunciado por lo demás la última línea tu estas bien

Comment: Añade a tu pregunta lo que te devuelve esa consulta.l y con gusto te ayudo.

Comment: Estas uniendo las tres tablas, es decir que solo vas a tener resultado si el user que consultas, es un profesor y tambien es un alumno.

Comment: Si hay datos en la tabla PROFESSOR es profesor, si no pasamos a realizar la consulta en la tabla STUDENT, un usuario con username "pepito" debe ser un profesor o un estudiante

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si solo necesitas saber si existe en la tabla STUDENT o PROFESSOR, te puede servir esta consulta.

```
SELECT t1.name FROM user
    inner join ( select id_user, name from student 
            union (select id_user, name from professor )
           ) t1 
    on t1.id_user = user.id 
 WHERE user.username = 'AER3';
```

Comment: me marca un error #1054 - La columna 'STUDENT.name' en field list es desconocida

Comment: Porque la consulta está mal, quítale el primer STUDENT.

Comment: Modifique mi consulta

Answer (score 1):

Esto es muy simple de resolver, si tienes dos consultas que ya te dan un resultado homogéneo puedes unirlas con `union`:

```
SELECT STUDENT.name, 'estudiante' as tipo
FROM USER
INNER JOIN STUDENT
ON STUDENT.id_user = USER.id
WHERE USER.username = '12345'

union

SELECT PROFESSOR.name, 'profesor' as tipo
FROM USER
INNER JOIN PROFESSOR
ON PROFESSOR.id_user = USER.id
WHERE USER.username = 'AER3'
```

el resultado sera:

```
name          |tipo
----------------------------
Alberto Cortez|estudiante
Juan Perez    |profesor
```

Al usar `union` puedes agregar mas campos ademas de `name`, pero ten en cuenta que el numero de columnas debe ser igual en las consultas que unes. De esa formal puedes buscar un usuario en 2 o mas tablas. No te compliques, saludos.